# Calculating the Derivative of a Complex Expression

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, logarithms

I am trying to find the derivative of the following expression:

$y = 1 + \frac{a}{1/x - a} + \frac{b/x}{(1/x - a)(1/x - b)} + \frac{c/x^2}{(1/x - a)(1/x - b)(1/x - c)}$

I have attempted to use basic differentiation rules, but the complexity of the expression is making it challenging. Could someone provide a step-by-step solution or guidance on how to approach this problem? I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos can you be more specific sir. I need someone to solve the question, can u help me?

Comment: @ganeshmurthy you have to understand that this website is not for exchanging *questions* and *answers*. Please see [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) And I don't recommend anyone to ask such basic questions here for basic questions we have [MSE Groups](https://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Maybe start with "Identify the individual terms of the function and their respective structures. Apply the quotient rule to differentiate the terms involving quotients. Expand the resulting expressions and combine like terms. Simplify the derivative by factoring out common factors or using other algebraic techniques.".

Comment: Also, perhaps "Differentiate each term separately and then combine the results. Use appropriate mathematical symbols to represent fractions, powers, and differentiation. Show all steps of the derivation to demonstrate the process clearly."

Comment: Ganesh, you shouldn't just post an identical copy of the same question in less than one hour. Please delete one, and fix the other. Also, FYI, if you're just looking for someone to provide you with the answer, that's not what we do here.